# how to convert this transpose code to mips assembly language

Tags: arrays, assembly, matrix, mips

I need to transpose a square matrix but I don't know how to do it in mips assembly language and I'm having difficulties to covert this algorithm to MIPS.
so please anybody can help??

```
M[][] = { {1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}, {13,14,15,16} }
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
    int temp = matrix[i][j];
    matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
    matrix[j][i] = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your C MIPS compiler can hep a lot.

Comment: for what I see, it will reveal several errors: 1) n,m are undeclared, 2) matrix is undeclared, 3) the definition of M has a syntax error. maybe more?

Comment: I'm **so** tempted to produce trolling answer with code without loops having all offsets hardcoded into... But I'm afraid this is genuine question of somebody who doesn't even realize how inappropriate this is for SO question, and the joke would fly over the head... (in worst case even being accepted in the school as solution).

Comment: :) with tag [c] added, I bet this would already be -10

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **gcc** or **lcc** compiler to convert C code to MIPS or any other assembly language.

**You may use below link:**

http://reliant.colab.duke.edu/c2mips/